# JavaScriptのconsole.logについて

Tags: javascript, array

jsなのですが、console.logで、オブジェクトや配列を表示した時、思った通りに値を取り出すってことが苦手です。
例えば、testという配列があって、以下のようなデータが、concole.logで表示された場合、

```
0: Item
attributes:
1: Item
attributes:
.
.
```

attributesの値がnullかどうかを調べたいのですが、どのようにすればいいでしょうか？
あるいは、配列やオブジェクトでつまづくので、何かいい考え方があれば知りたいです。
OSは、macOS High Siera
ブラウザは、chrome 69.0.3497.92
です

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！配列の内容がちょっとよく分からないので、Javascriptの表記で記述していただけますか？

Comment: javascriptの表記でっていう意味がわからなくて教えていただけますか？

Comment: 例えば、 `[ { attributes: null }, { attributes: { color: 'red' } } ]` などです。これは上記質問文の内容から推察したものですが、こういった形のデータを取り扱いたいという認識で正しいでしょうか？

Comment: Consoleの表示はブラウザ毎に異なるので、使用しているOSとブラウザも質問文中に明記してください。質問は`編集`から修正可能です。

Comment: そもそも、自分が作ったObjectなんです？別のAPIから吐き出されるObjectの中身を覗きたいとかですか？

Comment: 自分で作った訳ではないです。APIからの吐き出されるobjectの中身を覗きたいと思っています。

Comment: では、参考のために使用しているAPIを教えていただけますか？単純に`null`かどうかならIFで切り分ければいいと思います。

Comment: APIはちょっと見せれないのですいません。ifですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

参考までに：

```js
let obj = {};
obj.attr_1 = null;
obj.attr_2 = 2;
// objが各属性を持っているか調べる
obj.hasOwnProperty("attr_1")?console.log("obj has attr_1"):console.log("obj doesn't have attr_1");
obj.hasOwnProperty("attr_2")?console.log("obj has attr_2"):console.log("obj doesn't have attr_2");
obj.hasOwnProperty("attr_3")?console.log("obj has attr_3"):console.log("obj doesn't have attr_3");
// objの各属性がnullか調べる
obj.attr_1 === null?console.log("attr_1 is null"):console.log("attr_1 is not null");
obj.attr_2 === null?console.log("attr_2 is null"):console.log("attr_2 is not null");
obj.attr_3 === null?console.log("attr_3 is null"):console.log("attr_3 is not null");
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にします。

Answer (score 1):

ちょっとよくわからないので、
質問文中に記載されているConsole内容を再現してIFで比較しましたが、
こういうことではないのでしょうか？

```js
function Item(){this.attributes;}
//Initialize
var test = {};
for(var n=0;n<10;n++){
    test[n] = new Item();
    test[n].attributes = n;
}
console.log(test);
// Demo Null
test[3].attributes=null;
console.log(test);
// Check Values
if(null==test[0].attributes){console.log("0 is null");}
else{console.log("0 is Not null");}
if(null==test[3].attributes){console.log("3 is null");}
else{console.log("3 is Not null");}
```

Comment: 微妙に違うのですが、ニュアンス的には大丈夫です。ありがとうございます。